# How to image as fixed size while landscape screen in android

Tags: java, android

In my app, I have circle image view for profile picture layout.. If i choose image from gallery it fix perfectly in portrait view. But, Image automatically zoom in Landscape view. I want to fixed size in both(landscape and portrait) view.

Im used android:scaleType="fitXY" also.. But not support for CircleImageView.

Please anyone help me!!

My code here:

```html
 <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:src="@drawable/profilepic"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:border_width="2dp"
        app:border_color="@color/selected_gray"
        />
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: set the height also to wrap_content?

Comment: If i put height = wrap_content means.. Portrait view also zooming

Answer (score 0):

`CircleImageView` does't support `scaleType="fitXY"`

My approach for this type of problem is

```
public class SquareImageView  extends CircleImageView {

  ...

  @Override
  protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    int width = getMeasuredWidth();
    int height = getMeasuredHeight();
    setMeasuredDimension(height, height);
  }

  ...

}
```

that will make **width==height** that will make your images height and width same according to height